# Control wrapping and boxes width with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Hello I am new to using flexbox in CSS.
I have "boxes" that i need them to keep their width and be wrapped when the width is small.
On large screen:
[image: large screen]

On small screen:
[image: small screen]

```
.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  .item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1em;
    border:1px solid black;

  }
}
```

I need to keep the boxes look the same as on large screen but make the last one wrap and be in the center for example.
Here's the codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwbNXY

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your request, you can use a media query to give the items a fixed width (the minimum), and wrap them ([pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojgrXO?editors=110)):

```
@media (max-width: 260px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap; // make the items wrap

    .item {
      width: 30px; // give them a fixed width
      flex-grow: 0; // disable flex-grow
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you the key was flex-wrap also min-width can be used to maintain the width of the item and "induce" wrapping.